# Accessing a class functions via from a class decorator

Tags: python, exception, decorator, wrapper

I am stuck on an implementation problem.

```
class A(object):
    "class a variables"
    
    @execute
    def worker(self):
        try:
            "do an ETL operation"
        except Exception as e:
            raise ETL exception
            
    def letmehandleETLerrors(self):
        pass
    
    def letmehandleDataIntegrityErros(self):
        pass
        
    def letmehandleDataQualityErrors(self):
        pass
        
    def letmehandleDataUpdateErrors(self):
        pass
    
    def letmehandleDataDisplayErrors(self):
        pass
```

I have a class and inside that class one of it's methods called worker which calls other methods that do some data handling.

What I would like to accomplish is to have an centralized exception handling section in my application where I can offload all my exception handling and post activities to. We have lots of steps and wrangling to validate data so having exception handling all over the place is becoming tedious. So in a file called someExternalFile, I defined our centralized exception handling as such in summary:

```
class ETL_EXCEPTION(Exception):
    pass

class execute(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        pass
    
    def __call__(self,f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            try:
                r = f(*args)
            except ETL_EXCEPTION as etlEX:
                " i would like to call ClassA.letmehandleETLerrors()"
                pass
```

so essentially anytime an exception is raised anywhere in the other classes, I would like this decorator to route to the appropriate handlers to smoothly do post activities. The problem here is that I am trying to find a way to refer to f's class instance that is in scope for the decorator. I can get a reference to the class like so:

```
self.currentclass = f.__globals__[f.__qualname__.split('.')[0]]
```

but when I do self.currentclass.letmehandleETLerrors it says that letmehandleETLerrors needs a positional argument called self so in effect it created a new instance of ClassA i am thinking.

Would this be possible, or should I take this wrapper out of a class and define it as a method and pass Class A into it?

Comment: If you aren't doing anything in `execute.__init__`, you may as well replace the class `execute` with a simple function that does the same thing as `execute.__call__`.

Comment: `wrapped_f` already gets a value of type `ClassA`, namely `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting decorated function gets a value of type `ClassA` as its first argument, so you can use that to access `leetmehandleETLerrors`. Given that `execute` is tightly tied to `A`, it might as well be defined inside the class: just because it is doesn't mean it has to be exposed or used as an instance method.

```
class A:
    "class a variables"
    
    def _execute(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(self, *args):
            try:
                r = f(self, *args)
            except ETL_EXCEPTION as etlEX:
                self.letmehandleETLerrors()

    @_execute
    def worker(self):
        try:
            "do an ETL operation"
        except Exception as e:
            raise ETL exception
            
    def letmehandleETLerrors(self):
        pass
    
    def letmehandleDataIntegrityErros(self):
        pass
        
    def letmehandleDataQualityErrors(self):
        pass
        
    def letmehandleDataUpdateErrors(self):
        pass
    
    def letmehandleDataDisplayErrors(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner. I was considering this pattern as well. I will try your earlier comment on args[0] or just shifting to what you advised.

Comment: There's little difference between the two. I simply moved the definition of `execute` into the class and, under the assumption that it will *only* be used to decorated instance methods in `A` (rather than arbitrary functions) split `self` off from `args` for convenience.